# Prove MB bisects angle IMF

Tags: euclidean-geometry

$\Delta ABC$ inscribed $(O)$, incenter $I$, $(I)$ touch $BC$ at $D$. $AD \cap (O)=${$A;E$}. Let $M$ be the midpoint of $BC$ and $N$ be the midpoint of arc $BAC$. Let $EN$ intersect $(BIC)$ at $G$ ($G$ lies in $ABC$). $(AGE) \cap (BIC)=${$G;F$}. Prove $MB$ bisects $\angle IMF$
[image]

I have proved $\overline{G,D,F}$ by using power of a point. I need to prove $I,D,G,M$ concyclic (haven't proved yet), then the problem will be much easier ... Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Since $\angle IDM = 90^0$, IM is the diameter of (IDM). Let L be a point somewhere near F. LI can be drawn tangent to (IDM) at I. Then, $\angle IMD = \angle LID$.

[image]

Produce IM to K such that IM = MK. Then, M is the center of the circle passing I, and K cutting MF at H. Note that LI is also tangent to circle (IHK) at I. Then, $\angle LIH = \angle IKH$.

Combining the two results, we can say that (1) BDMC // HK and (2) I, D, H are collinear. By midpoint theorem, ID = DH. Required result follows.

Comment: I assume you meant $\angle LIH=\angle IHK$.  However, there does seem to be circular logic somewhere.  To know that $B$ and $HK$ are parallel, you need to know that $I$, $D$, and $H$ are collinear.  And you don't seem to be using how the points are constructed,.

Comment: @Batominovski No, it is $\angle LIH = \angle IKH$. Perhaps an added picture can make things more clear. I, D, and H are collinear because of (1); plus $\angle IDM = \angle IHK = 90^0$; and the two angles are in corresponding positions.

Comment: What do you mean "Let L be a point somewhere near F" ?

Comment: @RopuToran I just want to draw a line that is tangent to the circle IDM touching it at I. That is the blue line. I need to give that tangent line a name and therefore LI. L is also used (in the later stage) for naming some angles. For example, $\angle LID$.